# Mask sensitive data in Mule4 before logging

Tags: mule-esb

I have already gone through the below link to mask/hide/encrypt sensitive data before logging but unable to do so using Mule4. Can someone please share if implemented or suggestions?

http://bushorn.com/encrypting-a-json-element/

Answer (score 0):

The link is no longer available. I'll assume it is a method base on some log4j2 interception that will not work on Mule 4. What you can do is create a custom logging component with the Mule SDK and apply the same logic there, avoiding trying to intercept Mule 4 logging.